# split a string in to multiple strings

Tags: c#

```
123\r\n456t\r\n789
```

How can i split the string above in to multiple strings based on the string text
.split has only over load that takes char :(

Comment: What exact output you needed can you tell this was some what  unclear

Comment: Which .Net? At least in 4.0 there is an overload with `string` separators, I believe they were there in earlier versions.

Comment: string[] lines= logText.Split("\r\n"); I am expecting the string logText split in to multiple string

Comment: @user: But there are no newlines in your string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`string.Split` has supported an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) taking an array of string delimiters since .NET 2.0. For example:

```
string data = "123text456text789";
string[] delimiters = { "text" };
string[] pieces = data.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

use string.split("text"), hope it will help.

Comment: Doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to split 123, 456, 789 as you have \r\n after them.

Easiest way I see is

string textVal = "123\r\n456t\r\n789";

textVal = textVal.replace("\r", "").replace("\n",",");

string arrVal[] = textVal.split(',');

Now you have arrVal containing 123, 456, 789.

**Happy coding**

Answer (score 0):

String.Split supports also an array of strings. In your case you can do:

```
string s = "123\r\n456t\r\n789";
string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```